# Extracting values from pandas DataFrame using a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas Series that contains key-value pairs, where the key is the name of a column in my pandas DataFrame and the value is an index in that column of the DataFrame.

For example:

Series:
[Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBFWp.png)

Then in my DataFrame:
[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTZyB.png)

Therefore, from my DataFrame I want to extract the value at index 12 from my DataFrame for 'A', which is 435.81 . I want to put all these values into another Series, so something like { 'A': 435.81 , 'AAP': 468.97,...}

My reputation is low so I can't post my images as images instead of links (can someone help fix this? thanks!)

Comment: You need to frame your question better and give a better example of the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this indexing is what you're looking for.

```
pd.Series(np.diag(df.loc[ser,ser.axes[0]]), index=df.columns)
```

`df.loc` allows you to index based on string indices. You get your rows given from the values in `ser` (first positional argument in `df.loc`) and you get your column location from the labels of `ser` (I don't know if there is a better way to get the labels from a series than `ser.axes[0]`). The values you want are along the main diagonal of the result, so you take just the diagonal and associate them with the column labels.

The indexing I gave before only works if your DataFrame uses integer row indices, or if the data type of your Series values matches the DataFrame row indices. If you have a DataFrame with non-integer row indices, but still want to get values based on integer rows, then use the following (however, all indices from your series must be within the range of the DataFrame, which is not the case with 'AAL' being 1758 and only 12 rows, for example):

```
pd.Series(np.diag(df.iloc[ser,:].loc[:,ser.axes[0]]), index=df.columns)
```